# how do you extract the columns that contain a certain text/string in R

Tags: regex, r

I need to be able to extract columns that contain exact string that I am looking for. For example, I have this data frame x:

```
structure(list(Time = structure(1L, .Label = "1/1/2015", class = "factor"), 
    WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Phys.Mem.MB. = 3555L, 
    WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Phys.Mem.Free.MB. = 55L, 
    WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Swap.Free.MB. = 44L, 
    WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Cache.Free.MB. = 66L, 
    WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Swap.And.Cache.Free.MB. = 44L, 
    WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Percent.Free = 44L, 
    WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Round.Trip.Time = 44L), .Names = c("Time", 
"WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Phys.Mem.MB.", 
"WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Phys.Mem.Free.MB.", 
"WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Swap.Free.MB.", 
"WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Cache.Free.MB.", 
"WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Swap.And.Cache.Free.MB.", 
"WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Percent.Free", 
"WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Round.Trip.Time"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

I need to only extract the column that contains this exact match ".Total.Phys.Mem.MB."

When I do this:

```
x[,grepl(".Total.Phys.Mem.MB.", colnames(x)[2:ncol(x)])]
```

I dont get the column that contains this string in it ".Total.Phys.Mem.MB.". Is there a better way to extract the columns that contain the string in R?

Comment: Try `x[, grepl("\\.Total\\.Phys\\.Mem\\.MB\\.", colnames(x))]`

Comment: @David Arenburg, I also need to extrac the Time column. I tried this:  x[grepl("\\.Total\\.Phys\\.Mem\\.MB\\.", colnames(x)[2:ncol(x)])], the same, cannot extract the columns from the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

select(x, contains(".Total.Phys.Mem.MB."))
  WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Phys.Mem.MB.
1                                                                                    3555
```

Comment: can you do or (|) in dply contains. I tried this select(x, contains("Time"|".Total.Phys.Mem.MB.")), got this error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Answer (score 1):

Unless `fixed=TRUE` is defined, `grepl` recognizes the pattern as a regular expression; and in regex the dot is a character of special meaning which must be escaped to match a literal.

```
> x[grepl("\\.Total\\.Phys\\.Mem\\.MB\\.", colnames(x))]
  WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Phys.Mem.MB.
1                                                                                    3555
```

OR

```
> x[grepl('.Total.Phys.Mem.MB.', colnames(x), fixed=TRUE)]
  WTAD..Linux..Linux.Percent.of.Physical.Memory.and.Swap.Used.on.web02.Total.Phys.Mem.MB.
1                                                                                    3555
```

Comment: I need to extract the first column labeled Time from this data frame as well.